# ENOSPC vs ENOMEM when to use which?

Tags: c, linux, unix, error-handling, return-code

Linux/Unix defines plenty of relatively similar error codes. Are there any commonly followed conventions suggesting what types of errors should be bound to which error codes?

Let's say my function has some arbitrary container with fixed size (and can't be resized for arbitrary reasons not related to actual RAM usage). If code tries to push too many objects into containers should I rather return ENOMEM or ENOSPC? Is ENOSPC solely dedicated to persistent storage devices space or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error codes are *not* returned by programs, but by functions. See [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and [errno(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) with [intro(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/intro.3.html)

Correct programs are using somehow [exit(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html) (implicitly called by [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0) code when `main` is `return`ing an exit code) but see also [signal(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and [execve(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html). Use `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE`, but do also look inside `/usr/include/sysexits.h`

Read also [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) and [`man` pages](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/).

**Study for inspiration the source code of *existing* open source software**, including [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/), [GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/), [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/).

For kernel modules, see also code from [kernel.org](https://kernel.org/) and [kernelnewbies.org](https://kernelnewbies.org/)

Comment: Sorry i meant function. It was way too big mental shortcut but my "program" is FUSE filesystem so error codes my syscalls return propagate to applications that use my filesystem that's why I called it "returning code by program"